# post method is stucked on processing

Tags: php, javascript

Javascript request is stuck on ...processing.

And here is my javascript:

```
function checklink() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "new_item.php";
    var tratata = document.getElementById("yl1").value;
    var vars = "yl=" + tratata;

    hr.open("POST", url, true);

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Here is php which is located on the same page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["yl"])) {
  $yli = $_POST["yl"];
      /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, either in your browser or on the server?

Comment: im not getting any errors, it just shows "...processing" and stucks on it. And I can alert the variable from javascript, so the mistake is somewhere in connection.

Comment: It works fine for me as long as it can find new_item.php. Does the JS console have anything to say?

Comment: Also, what happens if you add `else console.log(hr)` to that condition in the `onreadystatechange` method?

Comment: it seems that something wrong with the server..

Comment: I think the response from the server is a `500 Internal Server Error` instead of `200 OK`. Check the nework section of the browser developer tools.